# how to append two list of one element and keep them still a list?

Tags: tcl

For example:

```
% set l [list a]
a
% set l [list $l b]
a b
% set l [list $l c]
{a b} c
```

Question:
The question because im coding when i get tclsh parse result.because i used regular expression to parser tclsh result as a string.so {a b} c and {{a} b} c} is different to me. i regular them split of "}"character. so i want to let the tclsh result format for "}" like this

```
a

{a} b 

{{a} b} c
```

exception:
i try the way

```
% set l [list a]
a
% set l [list "{$l}b"]
{{a}b}
% set l [list "{$l}c"]
{{{{a}b}}c}
```

Just as it looks，this result "{{{{a}b}}c}" has overmuch braces for me.
how to just change tcl.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not quite sure what you want, but there seems to be a bit of confusion about how braces work in Tcl - your desired results (interpreted as Tcl lists) mean the same things as what your example code produced:

Viewed as nested lists, `{{a} b} c` is the same as `{a b} c` (I've made the element values `a`, `b` and `c` instead of all `a` to make it easier to track):

```
set got  "{a b} c"
set want "{{a} b} c"

puts " got length: [llength $got]"     ;# prints " got length: 2"
puts "want length: [llength $want]"    ;# prints "want length: 2"

puts " got 0 0: ([lindex $got  0 0])"  ;# prints " got 0 0: (a)"
puts "want 0 0: ([lindex $want 0 0])"  ;# prints "want 0 0: (a)"

puts " got 0 1: ([lindex $got  0 1])"  ;# prints " got 0 1: (b)"
puts "want 0 1: ([lindex $want 0 1])"  ;# prints "want 0 1: (b)"

puts " got 1: ([lindex $got  1])"      ;# prints " got 1: (c)"
puts "want 1: ([lindex $want 1])"      ;# prints "want 1: (c)"
```

It's a common misunderstanding for programmers new to Tcl coming from other languages where quotes mean "this is a string" to think that braces mean "this is a list".  Quotes and braces don't *mean* things (about a type) in Tcl, they *do* things: they quote a sequence of characters as a single word even if they contain whitespace that would (in a command or list context) have broken them up into multiple words.  In the following, the values in all three variables are identical: the string `foo "bar" ba"z`, which, if interpreted as a list, contains the words: `foo`, `bar` and `ba"z`

```
set x {foo "bar" ba"z}
set y "foo \"bar\" ba\"z"
set z foo\ \"bar\"\ ba"z
```

To state it more formally, when interpreting a string as a list or command:

- a double quote character `"` as the first character of a word interprets all following characters until the next unescaped `"` as part of that word.  The `"` characters are not part of the word.
- an open brace character `{` as the first character of a word interprets all following characters until the matching close brace `}` as part of that word.  Braces nest, so that "matching" means: at a nesting level of 0 and not escaped.  The `{` and `}` characters are not part of the word.
- a quote `"` or open brace `{` in any position other than the first character of a word have no special action (but watch out for unmatched braces changing the interpretation of the brace-quoted word they're embedded in, like the `proc` body word).

So: both quotes `"` and braces `{}` at the start of a word act to change the parsing rules about the following characters so as to group them into that word until the matching end quote or close brace.  They differ in that braces nest but quotes don't.

When interpreting a string as a command (but not as list), there is an additional difference:

- characters grouped into a word by quotes `"` apply substitutions - so `$`, `\` and `[` are given special meaning, and start a variable, backslash and script substitution, respectively.
- characters grouped into a word by braces `{}` do not perform these substitutions (other than treating `\{` and `\}` as literal characters, but not substituting them), so the string value of the word is just the literal characters within the outer braces.

There are additional syntax differences between lists and commands (`\n`, `;`, line continuation), but they're out of scope for this answer.  See `man Tcl` for the formal rules (known as the "Dodekalogue" - the 12 syntax rules of Tcl).

All that said, I'm going to try to answer your question with some guesses at what you want:

If you want to incrementally build a flat list of three elements (I'm going to use `first val`, `second val` and `third val` here instead of single characters to avoid false patterns - the elements contain whitespace), you could do that like:

```
set l  [list {first val}]      ;# all these are equivalent
set l  [list [list first val]] ;# all these are equivalent
set l  [list "first val"]      ;# all these are equivalent
set l  [list first\ val]       ;# all these are equivalent
set l  first\\\ val            ;# all these are equivalent
set l  {{first val}}           ;# all these are equivalent

set l  [list {*}$l {second val}]
set l  [list {*}$l "third val"]

puts $l     ;# prints "{first val} {second val} {third val}"
```

... or ...

```
set l  {{first val}}
lappend l "second val"
lappend l {third val}
```

which leaves the same value in the variable `l`: the string `{first val} {second val} {third val}`.

If you meant something else, leave a comment to clarify and I'll edit the answer to include that interpretation.

Comment: Thanks very much for your explanation.now i know more rules about tcl command. Indeed i used it in c++ program with tclsh. The question i want to ask is coding when i get tclsh parse result.because i used regular expression to parser tclsh result as a string.so `{a b} c` and `{{a} b} c}` is different to me. i regular them split of "}"character，so i understand this result.

Comment: I see, parsing Tcl lists from other languages is quite a lot more tricky than you might expect.  I did it from Javascript, take a look at the function `list2array` in https://github.com/cyanogilvie/Tcl.js/blob/master/es6/list.js which I believe does it correctly, although it might be better to output the data from Tcl in a well-known format like JSON: https://github.com/RubyLane/rl_json or XML: http://www.tdom.org/

Comment: Although, since your case is extracting values from Tcl lists in c++, I'd just link libtcl and use `Tcl_ListObjGetElements`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832265/tcl-api-how-to-get-a-list-from-tcl

Answer (score 1):

You *can* get exactly what you say you are after by doing string operations (*every* value in Tcl is a string).

```
set l a
set l "{$l} a" 
set l "{$l} a" 
# {{a} a} a
```

But *this is not a list operation.* List operations don't produce that with simple words because they try to omit braces wherever possible (and prefer braces to backslashes; backslashes are only used in list rendering as a last resort). Note however, if you do:

```
set l [list a]
set l [list $l a]
set l [list $l a]
```

Then you can definitely do `lindex $l 0 0 0` to get that first `a`, and that will definitely continue to work if you change those `a`s to any other arbitrary value. The thing I did with string processing does *not* make that guarantee at all (considering the "leaf" string `}foo` for a tricky edge case).

Letting lists be lists and general strings be general strings is preferable to having a fight with the list renderer and parser over exactly what is a list.